# Can Dawnguard Scyir get 4 damage dice on a charge?

Tags: warmachine

[Dawnguard Scyir](http://privateerpress.com/warmachine/gallery/retribution-of-scyrah/solos/dawnguard-scyir) has the ability `Flank[Faction Warjack]`. If a warjack was in melee with a given enemy model and the Scyir charged into combat with that model, would he get four dice on the damage roll?

The same question would then apply to [Sword Knights](http://privateerpress.com/warmachine/gallery/cygnar/units/sword-knight-unit), which have the same `Flank` ability.

Comment: For people who stumble onto this old question, most of the models have been tweaked in a lot of ways in the last 8 years. While Sword Knights still have `Flank[Faction Warjack]`, the Dawnguard Scyir lost `Flank` entirely and picked up `Weapon Master` on his sword. But for the purposes of how `Flank` works in general, that hasn't changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the proviso that I'm not personally a player of Warmachine, I found this link to the Privateer Press forums where the truly knowledgeable people hang out:

http://privateerpressforums.com/showthread.php?19636-Dawnguard-Scyir

Quite close to the top of this thread, a chap who seems to know what he's doing says:

> Now the Scyir isn't a weapon master
>   but has flank, so in order to get the
>   three dice on damage (4 if you charge)
>   you need to have a jack be in melee
>   range. So the jack has to get in melee
>   before the Scyir activates. But if the
>   Jack activates before the Scyir it's
>   drive is useless as it will not need
>   to re-roll nothing.

I think that "three dice on damage (4 if you charge)" answers your question - a charging flank attack does indeed deal 4 dice damage!

As far as I can make out, multiple instances of flank don't stack, but there's no problem getting a bonus both from flanking and charging...

Answer (score 5):

The reason you can get both bonuses, is because a charge Boosts the damage roll, while the flanking adds an extra die.  A die roll (damage or attack) can only be boosted once, no matter the source, but can have extra dice added from other rules.  So a boost adds an extra die, but is itself unique - adding an extra die from other effects that do not boost will still add the extra die.

And, as thesunneversets noted, you cannot get the flanking bonus more than once per damage roll.